# Spring: How to commit transaction before entering @AfterReturning advice

Tags: java, spring, service, transactions, aop

I've got a transactional service class:

```
@Service
@Transactional(...)
public class MyService() {

    public void myFunc() { 
       // some code
    }

}
```

Also the following Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect() {

    @AfterReturning(value = "execution(...") // pointcut matching myFunc()'s signature
    public void doSomethingAfterMyFunc() { 
       // some code
    }

}
```

The problem I'm facing is that upon entering the `@AfterReturning` advice, the transaction created from the execution of `myFunc()` is not yet committed, so the advice shares the same transaction. From what I've read this behavior is to be expected, but for my purposes I need the opposite - is there a way to commit `myFunc()`'s transaction before entering the advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Explicitly set the `order` on `@EnableTransactionManagement` and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`. Make sure the latter goes first.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of the `@Transactional` Aspect, so you have 2 aspects in your code so you have to set the `Order` as explained https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering

In your code you could set the order of your own aspect `MyAspect` like the following:

```
@Aspect
@Order(1)
public class MyAspect() {
 //your code here
}
```

By specifying its order to 1 and since the rule is that:

> On the way out from the joinpoint, the advice with highest Order value
>   gets executed first.

the `@Transactional` Aspect will be executed prior yours so `myFunc` will get commited and then `doSomethingAfterMyFunc` will be executed.

Comment: What you're saying seems logical and I tried it. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well we had exactly the same problem in our project and we solved it by setting the `Order` in our `Aspect`. Have you also set the order in `@EnableTransactionManagement ` as per @M.Deinum suggested? If you do it must be higher than 1. Although the default value is already much greater than 1. It should have worked in your project too.

Comment: Yes, I tried everything. At the end of the day, I ended up using a @TransactionalEventListener instead of a AfterReturning advice to run the code needed after myFunc() finished.

Comment: I know this is old, but `@Transactional` uses the lowest precedence (Integer.MAX_VALUE). So setting order will no longer work, since any number is a higher precedence than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

You can possibly change the default precedence for Transactional, but i like your idea with the `@TransactionalEventListener better`